# .Net Core - EF Core - Context modelBuilder issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, data-binding, entity-framework-core

I've upgraded my project from EF6 to .NET Core & EF Core, but what worked well in the old version, is now not working and I don't know how to modify the implementation, I would need little help.

I am connecting Teachers and Students with classes, Teacher and Student are profiles, which can be connected separately.

My models:

```
public class Teacher : Profile, IClsModel, IMemberContainer
{
    public Teacher() :base()
    {
        Cls = new List<ProfileClass>();
    }

    public Teacher(RegisterModel model): base(model)
    {
        Cls = new List<ProfileClass>();
    }

    [DisplayName("Classes")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProfileClass> Cls { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Profile, IClsModel
{
    public Student():base()
    {
        Cls = new List<ProfileClass>();
    }

    public Student(RegisterModel model):base(model)
    {
        Cls = new List<ProfileClass>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Classes")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProfileClass> Cls { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileClass
{
    public ProfileClass()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int ProfileClassId { get; set; }

    public int? ClassId { get; set; }
    public long? ProfileId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeacherProfile")]
    public virtual Profile TeacherProfile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentProfile")]
    public virtual Profile StudentProfile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClassId")]
    public virtual Cls Cls { get; set; }
}
```

Builder in the context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>()
                   .HasMany(u => u.Cls)
                   .WithOne(ul => (Teacher)ul.TeacherProfile).IsRequired()
                   .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.ProfileId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                   .HasMany(u => u.Cls)
                   .WithOne(ul => (Student)ul.StudentProfile).IsRequired()
                   .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.ProfileId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

The exceptions are the followings:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'TeacherProfile' cannot be removed from entity type 'ProfileClass' because it is being used in the foreign key {'TeacherProfile'} on 'ProfileClass'.
> All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed.'

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'StudentProfile' cannot be removed from entity type 'ProfileClass' because it is being used in the foreign key {'StudentProfile'} on 'ProfileClass'.
> All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed.'

Comment: Please add all classes/interfaces required to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Rmoving the `ForeignKey` annotations in `ProfileClass` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete related records, you must firstly delete from related tables. You can't delete StudentProfile or TeacherProfile without delete first from ProfileClass.